# How to remove air from water supply line?

Tags: water, water-pressure

We live in a neighborhood where 20 of us all share a private well. Our water is very sputtery and also VERY fizzy when it comes out - lots of air coming out of it no matter where you are getting it from in the house.

The well operator has told us that the "occasional" buildup of air coming into our homes from the main is likely due to air being trapped in the horizontal pipes from the main to the houses or in there. But it's getting a little ridiculous lately.

Is there a way to eliminate / purge the air in the pipes and alleviate the air dissolved in the water as well - before it get's too far into our home system? Would a pressure tank do this? I need like a buffer / normalizer for the water coming from the supply basically. Sometimes it's so bad it will take a long time to even fill the toilet tank because of the violent sputtering.

We've tried bleeding the pipes and it usually hisses in the morning really bad and very late at night as well - but is generally OK through the day after it get's is all out.

No leaks or anything in the home - we are not the only ones on the well having this type of issue either.

Comment: An open or vented header-tank would prevent air reaching taps/faucets.

Comment: make sure the inlet pipe in the tank/well is completely submerged and leak-free.

Comment: I think you need a self venting header tank. make sure to plumb the vent to a drain or outside the house as they so spit water every now and then. small tanks less than $50 may work but to make sure as it sounds like you have a lot of air a larger tank would be better. Since it is a community system and others are having this problem you may be able to get them to install one after the pump / main pressure tank to solve the problem for everyone.

Comment: So this would be a new water heater then? Nothing I can add on?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an automatic air vent for the water supply. It has a air chamber and a float that will automatically bleed the accumulated air. They are also relatively inexpensive.

The automatic air vent is commonly used for for hydronic water heating systems but make sure its approved for potable water in your case.

This Honeywell EA122A1028 should work.
[Honeywell EA122A1028](http://www.supplyhouse.com/Honeywell-Braukmann-EA122A1028-Automatic-air-vent-with-built-in-shut-off-valve-EPDM-seat-disc-and-O-ring)

Comment: +1 Likely want a good sized tank for it to sit on top of - plumb supply in a higher side opening, draw for house off a lower opening.

Comment: Fantastic - this looks promising! Going to do some more research, thanks!

Comment: Looks like these are for pressure tanks, which I usually see just off the supply from the heater. Can I put a pressure tank with this vent before, say, my softener even? As to treat cold and hot lines?

Comment: I don't know how an air vent would help with a bladder pressure tank, but automatic air vents are commonly paired with hydronic air scoops to remove air from flowing water. But any plain tank like what Ecnerwal mentioned can be used to slow down water flow, giving enough time for the bubbles to rise and accumulate to be vented. It should be fine venting before the water softener, and these are vents are designed to handle hot water.